# What can I do with this noisy answers?

Tags: discussion, flags, answer-quality, popularity, protected-questions

More than 6 years ago <sup>(in a galaxy far far away)</sup> someone asked this question [How to get the month name in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975531/how-to-get-the-monthname-in-c?answertab=oldest#tab-top) which get 4 quite good answers within 5 minutes.

Then, last year (2015), 4 users (3 with 1 rep) answered with part of code from the others' answers.

Should I do something with this answers that, IMO, are noise? If so *what* can I do?

Here are the flag option:

- <strike>*spam*</strike>
- <strike>*rude or abusive*</strike>
- <strike>*not an answer*</strike>
- *very low quality*: This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.
- *in need of moderator*: intervention A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. Be specific and detailed!

  VLQ: The answers doesn't fit the description but are (still IMO) *useless*;

  INOM: I don't think that bothering a mod with this question is the rigth thing to do.

Comment: That's what the *protect* feature is intended to do.  Done.  If you don't have enough rep (15K required) then you can flag a moderator.  He can also *lock* it, the bigger weapon.

Comment: I wouldn't bother flagging as the selected answer in the dupe suggests.  Just downvote.  Enough downvotes and people can vote to delete.

Comment: @Will I'll use downvote when I'll be 25k+ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget about the "Downvote" option!

As you mentioned, these examples don't really require mod intervention. Just a downvote will get the message across to future visitors.

Additionally, <strike>I've</strike> [Hans Passant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) <sub>(You ninja!)</sub> has taken the liberty to "[protect](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions)" the question, so users need a minimum of 10 rep to answer it.